# Change button color if its value is less than X

Tags: java, android

I want to change the color of the button if the value it contains is less than X. Example:

```
String hour = "10:15";
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("10:10");
```

10:10 is the hours:minutes value
If 10:10 is less than hour (10:15) = btn.setBackgroundColor(...).

Theo logic:

```
if (btn.getText <= hour) { 
btn.setBackgroundColor(...); 
}
```

Help me PLS, Thank you!!!

I've tried several things, something ate the logic above using several methods, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just my logic:
First you need to try to separate the string from button.
You can do it using the split function, example:

```
String btnString= btn.getText();
String[] resultBtn = btnString.split(":");
String hour = "10:15";
String[] resultHour = hour.split(":");
```

With this you have two parts, resultBtn[0] is hours and resultBtn[1] minutes.
It's the same with resultHour.
Now I guess we are ready to do your logic, with some diferences:

```
// To make easier
   int btnHour = Integer.parseInt(resultBtn[0]);
   int btnMinutes = Integer.parseInt(resultBtn[1]); 
   int hHour = Integer.parseInt(resultHour[0]);
   int hMinutes = Integer.parseInt(resultHour[1]);

   if (btnHour <= hHour && btnMinutes <= hMinutes) { 
       btn.setBackgroundColor(...); 
    }
```

Comment: Note 1000!!! Spectacular, sensational. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I just adapted it like this now: int btnHour = Interger.parseInt(resultBtn[0]+resultBtn[1]; The sams with hHour.... And only If (btnHour <= hHour){}